# How can I make the checkmark in this MenuItem respect the overall Foreground color?

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

I am making a menu using `MenuItem` controls placed inside of a `StackPanel`.

Here's an example of the menu item XAML:

```
<Border Grid.Column="1"
        Background="Black"
        BorderBrush="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="1"
        Opacity="0.8"
        Padding="3">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <MenuItem Foreground="White"
                  Header="Show Mini Map"
                  IsCheckable="True"
                  IsChecked="{Binding ShowMiniMap, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        ...more items...
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

...and here's what it looks like on-screen:

[image]

You can see how the checked items have the usual blue ring around the checkmark, and the checkmark is there...it's just black.  Why does it not respect the item's `Foreground` property?

Is there a way to make it do so without having to take on maintenance of a gazillion-line template override?  The examples I've found online thus far are incredibly ridiculous for such a small thing.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no single setting you can change/override to do this, but if you are using VS2017 (maybe this works in older versions too), you can right-click one of the MenuItems, select "Edit Template" and adjust the `Fill` property of `Glyph`.

Comment: The default MenuItem template in Windows 7 (we just upgraded from flint knives to bronze) has `Fill="#FF0C12A1"` for the menu item glyph. You could probably write code to walk the menu and dig around in the visual tree of each item. Ugly, but arguably less ugly than making your application use some particular template version for all eternity.

Comment: Too bad no one had the foresight to realize that the thing might some day end up on a background that wasn't white...